# Desativando evento CLICK do ActionLink

Tags: html, eventos, button

Tenho o seguinte link na minha view :

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Editar", new { id = item.ID }, new { @id = "btnEditar" })
```

E ao carregar a página, tenho que bloquear esse link, conforme o perfil do usuário. Estou tentando desativar o click do link dessa maneira :

```
$('#btnEditar').prop('disabled', true);
$('#btnEditar').css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
```

Porém, ao clicar no botão, está sendo disparado o evento, o que não quero. O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido. Fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
$('#btnEditar').css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
$('#btnEditar').click(function () { return false; });
```